# Is it possible to modify fields using a LINQ expression without using a SELECT?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to populate a list of PhraseSource. Following this I am using a foreach to modify the list:

```
List<PhraseSource> phraseSources = App.DB.db1.Table<PhraseSource>().ToList();

List<PhraseSource> phraseSources2 = phraseSources
    .Where(p => categorySources.Any(c => c.Id == p.CategoryId)).ToList();

foreach (var item in phraseSources2)
{
    item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
    item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 100);
}
```

My knowledge of LINQ is pretty limited and this was the code given to me.

Is there a way I could combine the foreach into the LINQ expression or must I use a foreach in this way to modify the data?  Note that I think I could do the with a SELECT but I am wondering if there is another way as PhraseSource has a lot of fields.

Comment: LIN**Q** is to query a datasource, not to modify it. It is strongly recommended to not abuse LINQ to modify it. Why do you want it?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I didn't know that.  So you are suggesting that it's best to just leave the foreach?  Thanks

Comment: No.  To be able to change values in a database you need to get the rows affected using a WHERE.  Otherwise you will end up changing every row of the database with the same new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIN**Q** is to query a datasource, not to modify it. It is strongly recommended to not abuse LINQ to modify it. In this case you have a list so you could use `List.ForEach`:

```
phraseSources2.ForEach(item => {
    item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
    item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 100);
});
```

Although i don't see the benefit over `foreach`.

For what it's worth, you can write an extension which allows that with any sequence:

```
public static void ForEachDo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> doWithEveryItem, Action doIfEmpty = null)
{
    bool isEmpty = true;
    foreach (T item in seq)
    {
        isEmpty = false;
        doWithEveryItem(item);
    }
    if (isEmpty && doIfEmpty != null)
        doIfEmpty();
}
```

Now you could use it even if it's not a list:

```
var phraseSources2 = phraseSources.Where(p => categorySources.Any(c => c.Id == p.CategoryId));
phraseSources2.ForEachDo(item=> {
    item.OneHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
    item.TwoHash = Math.Abs(item.Id.GetHashCode() % 100);
})
```

But again, `foreach` is the perfect tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Although LINQ does not let you modify items, you have several options at your disposal:

- Since `OneHash` and `TwoHash` are computed based on other properties of `item`, you can replace stored properties with computed ones
- If you do not need to modify items inside `phraseSources` (which you would need to do if you plan to save them) you could create copies with computed properties set
- If `OneHash` and `TwoHash` are not stored in the `PhraseSource` table, you could remove them from `PhraseSource` object, and add them as properties of an anonymous "wrapper" object. This would let you compute properties in a LINQ query.

The first approach would look like this:

```
public class PhraseSource {
    ...
    public int OneHash => Id.GetHashCode() % 10;
    public int TwoHash => Id.GetHashCode() % 100;
    ...
}
```

Note: in older C# versions that do not support lambda-bodied properties use the getter syntax:

```
public class PhraseSource {
    ...
    public int OneHash { get { return Id.GetHashCode() % 10; } }
    public int TwoHash { get { return Id.GetHashCode() % 100; } }
    ...
}
```